# Duda sobre Return en metodo

Tags: java

Estoy empezando a estudiar Java y estoy escribiendo un metodo muy sencillo que recibe como parámetro un entero y me debe devolver un String, el programa no me marca errores, mi duda es, porque a la hora de ejecutar no me devuelve nada, he hecho varias pruebas y creo que la falla esta en el return, donde
podría estarme equivocando?, agradezco de antemano su ayuda. Dejo el código aquí abajo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n= 2;
    
    prueba(n);  
}

public static String prueba (int n) {
            
    if (n == 2){
        return "Si";
    } else{
        return "No";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Te falta el objeto instanciado de la clase y por medio de dicho objeto acceder al método que hace el retorno del string

Comment: Con algo así: **`MyClass clase = new MyClass();
    
    System.out.println(clase.prueba(10));`** en tu main debe funcionar

Comment: No estás mostrando nada, si haces por ejemplo esto verás la salida: `System.out.println( prueba(n) );` y si lo necesitas para algo más, como dice @BetaM, asigna la llamada del método a un objeto del tipo que devuelve.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que sucede es que devuelve un valor de tipo String pero este valor no lo estas imprimiendo, para imprimirlo en la consola usa

```
System.out.println("hola Jose");
```

Revisa la documentaciòn:

[System.out.println()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)

En el caso de tu còdigo serìa:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n= 2;
    
    System.out.println("valor obtenido: " + prueba(n));  
}

public static String prueba (int n) {
            
    if (n == 2){
        return "Si";
    } else{
        return "No";
    }
    
}
```

---

Puedes incluso asignar el valor obtenido a una variable y posteriormente imprimirlo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n= 2;

    String resultado = prueba(n);
    System.out.println("valor obtenido: " + resultado);  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo desde clases diferentes, instalaciando la nueva clase y controlando la respuesta mediante una variable con la que luego podrías validar el resultado

Desde la clase programa y el método main

```
 public class programa {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          //instancias la clase prueba creada
          prueba miPrueba = new prueba();
          //instancias la clase teclado
          Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
          //pides un número por teclado
          System.out.println("Escriba un número: ");
          //guardas ese número en la variable "n"
          int n = teclado.nextInt();
          //al llamar al método guardas el resultado en el String respuesta y envias como parámetro el número recogido por teclado
          String respuesta = miPrueba.metodoPrueba(n);
          //evaluas el resultado. (Si el resultado es igual a "Si"
          if (respuesta.equals("Si")){
              System.out.println("El valor es el número 2");
          }
          //Si el resultado no es igual a "Si"
          else{
              System.out.println("El valor es cualquier número excepto el 2");
          }
      }
 }
```

Creas una nueva clase prueba

```
  public class prueba {
      //en la clase prueba creas el metodoPrueba
      public String metodoPrueba(int n){
          String respuesta = "NO";
          if (n == 2){
             respuesta = "Si";
          } 
          return respuesta;
      }
  }
```